# Is my solution to this homework problem in geometry correct? Can we avoid trigonometry in solving this?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to solve this nice homework problem in (Euclidean) geometry - https://snipboard.io/oVp3Ic.jpg, and I wrote down a detailed solution with step-by-step explanation at: https://snipboard.io/ZzdsA0.jpg **(click on the + sign on the image to make it bigger**). Note that in the picture of the solution, DE=7cm. Also, note that, in the picture of the problem, the drawings aren't correct, because some sides AB an CE supposed to be parallel, but they're not drawn to be so, which could be misleading.

Some steps in the solution I gave:

i) I first solved for the angle ABC

ii) I expressed BC and CD as a trigonometric functions of the angle ABC (called $\theta.)$

iii) Observed $x=BC + CD.$

I'd greatly appreciate if you could please the take a bit of time to see if my solution is correct, and if we can avoid the use of trigonometry in solving this problem? I think in the picture of the solution, if you consider the similar right-angles triangles $CDE$ and $CGB,$ then we can write:

$$\frac{DE}{CE}=\frac{CG}{BG}$$

which is, algbraically ( where $y=AG$ in the picture of the solution.):

$$\frac{7}{6+y}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{(9-y)^2 + 3^2}}.$$

Comment: It's very difficult to read the written-down solution — I would heartily encourage transcribing it here. There is definitely a nice non-trigonometric solution to the problem that only makes use of the Pythagorean theorem, though.

Comment: As a hint: since the 3cm and 6cm sides are at right angles, they form two sides of a rectangle. Draw the other two sides of that rectangle, and look at what that tells you about the distance from the bottom-left corner to the point at the corner of the 6cm and 7cm lines.

Comment: The fact that the problem doesn't draw orthogonal sides at right angles is deeply disappointing — not your fault, of course, but disappointing.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "distance from the bottom-left corner to the point at the corner of the 6cm and 7cm lines", you mean from B to E in the picture of the solution? I think that may be too difficult to find. BTW, if you extend the 6cm side EF in my solution to the South West, it won't pass through the bottom left point B...

BTW, have you enlarged the photo of the solution and then tried to read it? I tried this and the writings seem clear...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sorry but I'm still not sure, what can we say about AB an AG except from the fact that B,G,A are colinear? Care to elaborate a bit or write an answer please?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This is the step I used trigonometry? Are you using similar triangles BCG and CDE and their side ratios to find BG?

Comment: Ack. I hadn't realized that you already had a point $G$ in the diagram; apologies for that. :/ (This is why I so strongly recommend transcribing, BTW.) I mean a new point $H$ that would form the fourth of the rectangle with $A$, $E$, and $F$. Then $|AH|=|EF|$ because of the rectangle, and $B$, $A$, and $H$ are all still collinear, so you can find $|BH|=|BA|+|AH|$ and $|EH|=|AF|$ (again from the rectangle), with $BH$ and $EH$ at right angles...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for that explanation. What I'm still not sure though, is how finding BH helps in finding BD? $x=$BD is clearly not equal to BH. BTW, I updated my question with another alternate method, using similar triangles.

Comment: The idea is that $|BH|$ finds you $|BE|$ by the Pythagorean theorem, and then $|BE|$ finds you $|BD|$ also by the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah I see it now, but the similar triangle idea I posted also works it seems :) Thank you for this alternate idea though, that I fully digested by now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is just to find the common hypotenuse of two right triangles:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I accepted it :) Do you've the LaTeX code for drawing that nice figure? If yes, could you please share it? I went into the 'edit' section of your answer but couldn't see the code, as everything is in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oORkq.png

Comment: @Stat_math, Thank you too, unfortunately that drawing is just a picture and not a LaTeX  code.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-

$(1)$ Plot in the cartesian plane the red broken line of vertices $A=(0,0),B=(0,9),C=(3,9),D=(3,15)$ as in the attached figure. This broken line satisfies the wanted condition of perpendicularity.

$(2)$ Find the tangent from the point $A$ to the circle of equation $(x-3)^2+(y-15)^2=7^2$.

You must find $x\approx13.60120$.

[image]